# Need assistance in reshaping the data

Tags: r, reshape2, melt, dcast

I'm new here and also to R world.
I have been trying to  reshape the data but i couldn't do it after going through dcast, melt ,reshape options.

my data looks like,
[original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWTql.jpg)

> TESTCODE BATCHNUMBER BATCHVALUE DATALINEID
>
> test        1           100        _83281
>      test        1            99        _83284
>      test        1           100        _83287
>      test        1           101        _83290
>      test        2           101        _83281
>      test        2            95        _83284
>      test        2            99        _83287
>      test        2            98        _83290
>      test        3            99        _83281
>      test        3           103        _83284
>      test        3           102        _83287
>      test        3           100        _83290

and it needs to be transformed to something like this,

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa3dv.png)

> TESTCODE   DATALINEID   BATCH1   BATCH2   BATCH3
>
> ```
>  TEST     _83281       100      101       99
>  TEST     _83284        99       95      103
>  TEST     _83287       100       99      102
>  TEST     _83290       101       98      100
> ```

i have tried using 
dcast(TEST,TESTCODE+DATALINEID ~., value.var = "BATCHVALUE") , which gives output like

```
TESTCODE   DATALINEID  .
 test     _83281      3
 test     _83284      3
 test     _83287      3
 test     _83290      3
```

and also
dcast(TEST, TESTCODE+BATCHNUMBER ~ DATALINEID +., value.var = "BATCHVALUE")

TESTCODE BATCHNUMBER _83281 _83284 _83287 _83290

```
 test           1    100     99    100    101
 test           2    101     95     99     98
 test           3     99    103    102    100
```

Looking forward to the replies, thereby learning something new.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer,

dcast(data = TEST,formula =TESTCODE+DATALINEID~BATCHNUMBER, value.var="BATCHVALUE")

The desired output,

> TESTCODE DATALINEID   1       2       3

```
test     _83281    100    101     99
test     _83284     99     95    103
test     _83287    100     99    102
test     _83290    101     98    100
```